# Alteração de DisplayName?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

É possível alterar o DisplayName de uma classe?
Consigo acessar as propriedades dela, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a alteração.

[image: DisplayName]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Conforme documentação disponível [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=net-5.0), basta fazer isto:

```
// This property exists only to demonstrate the 
// DisplayName attribute. When this control 
// is attached to a PropertyGrid control, the
// property will appear as "RenamedProperty"
// instead of "MisnamedProperty".
[Description("Demonstrates DisplayNameAttribute.")]
[DisplayName("RenamedProperty")]
public bool MisnamedProperty
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```